# Guarantee that the function will be called after another function in the same scope in C#

Tags: c#

My question is mostly about the code safety case in C#.

Here is the code:

```
void foo() {
 theFirst();
 //some code which needs to call theFirst() before executing goes here
 definitelyShouldBeCalledAfterTheFirst();
}
```

Now I want to ensure that in every scope (basically any method) where the function `theFirst()` is called the function `definitelyShouldBeCalledAfterTheFirst()` is called afterwards somewhere in the same scope. Between `theFirst()` and `definitelyShouldBeCalledAfterTheFirst()` calls I need to call other functions most of the time and I can not call the functions after `definitelyShouldBeCalledAfterTheFirst()` or before `theFirst()`.

Comment: The key would be to make it so the second method is called from the first method.

Comment: New func that calls theFirst and put the other call in a finally block

Comment: Are the two functions you want to call coupled logically in some fashion?  You could use an `IDisposable` that does it, then always use a using block to invoke it - the second function would be called when the object is "disposed".

Comment: @JamesThorpe, yes, of course, they are coupled.

Comment: There is nothing that can _enforce_ this requirement. The primary pattern in .NET that displays this behavior is the `IDisposable` pattern, and nothing _enforces_ that `Dispose()` is called on the object in the same scope; it only publishes that it _should_ be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this with delegates can help:

```
void ExecuteBetweenFirstAndSecond(Action action)
{
    bool success = false;

    try
    {
       First();
       success = true;
       action?.Invoke();
    }
    finally
    {
       //Uncomment if you want to execute Second only if First wast executed successfully
       //if (success)     
       Second();
    }                   
}
```

Comment: Pretty good solution, but I hope for even a better one. If it won`t come soon, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Do you consider exception handling?  Should the second and the code between them be executed in case of exception in first?

Comment: Edited to add some exception handling logic

Comment: What if Second() throws?

Comment: The author didn't specify the requirements for the Second. Nothing in requirements says that the code in it should never fail.

Comment: Moreover, if you want some extra guarantees you can mark the try block as CER (constrained execution region, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/constrained-execution-regions).

Comment: It makes the CLR to do the loading of types and assemblies referenced in finally block or JIT compilation of methods called in finally block before the code in try block is executed. This could prevent the situation when First method was executed but the Second wasn't because it is in another assembly which raised exception on load for some reason. Or there weren't enough memory in the system for the  creation of type objects and the OutOfMemoryException was thrown

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to achieve this, depending on context.

@SENya gives a [great option using delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49325556/361842).

One alternative is where you have a shared base class (though this option is only applicable to a small subset of scenarios).

```
abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    void doFirst() =>
        Debug.WriteLine("Done First");
    void definitelyShouldBeCalledAfterTheFirst() =>
        Debug.WriteLine("Done After First");    
    protected virtual void doSomething() => 
        Debug.WriteLine("between first and after first");
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        doFirst();
        doSomething();
        definitelyShouldBeCalledAfterTheFirst();
    }
}

class MyClass: MyBaseClass {}
class MyOtherClass: MyBaseClass 
{
    protected override void doSomething() =>
        Debug.WriteLine("something else happens now");
}

void Main()
{
    var a = new MyClass();
    a.DoStuff();
    /* outputs:
        Done First
        between first and after first
        Done After First
    */
    var b = new MyOtherClass();
    b.DoStuff();
    /* outputs:
        Done First
        something else happens now
        Done After First
    */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you have following requirements:

1. Have a function that always executed the first,
2. Have a function that always executed the last,
3. Some other functions that can be executed in any order but not first or last.

What function is always executes and executes the first? a constructor...
So if you create a class and put a call to your `First()` function in constructor the requirement #1 is fulfilled.

The insuring that order of execution is met requirement #3 is easy. No code will be executed before constructor. And if you put a flag that function `Last()` has been already executed you can check that flag in the beginning of each function and throw / return if it is set.

The hardest part is to ensure execution of the `Last()` function. The closest guarantee will be to implement IDisposable but you cannot guarantee that your class will be called within `using`.

So we end up with something along those lines:

```
public sealed class Foo: IDisposable
{
    private bool isLastCalled = false;

    public Foo()
    {
        First();
    }


    public void First()
    {
        if (isLastCalled) return;

        // do something...
    }
    public void Other()
    {
        if (isLastCalled) return;

        // do something...
    }

    public void Last()
    {
        if (isLastCalled) return;

        isLastCalled = true;

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Last();
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        Last();
    }
}
```

Additional notes:

- `First()` will be called automatically from constructor but you can call it again as any other before `Last()` is called. if this is not your intention - make the function `private` and remove check for the flag
- You can call `Last()` explicitly or it will be called automatically when the instance is out of the scope. If you do not need to call it explicitly make it `private` too

Comment: This is not strictly enforcing execution. First of all, if I were to forgot to call the Dispose, or wrap the call in the using block, then the Second is executed on finalizer, which is executed on separate thread at some indefinite time. There could be a lot of code executed in between. Not to mention that finalizer introduces extra overhead for a GC.

Comment: Moreover, this isn't enforcing anything strictly cause I can call GS.SuppressFinalize on the object and then the Second won't be called.
Imho, the IDispose should be used for what it was introduced - the resources cleanup and disposal. It could create unclear code if at some place you used IDispose for cleanup and at other place - for syntax sugar

Comment: Secondly, it's not very convenient - do you need to create new class which will override Other just for every possible code between First and Second?

Answer (score 0):

This is what try-finally is for. Very simple. If the call to theFirst succeeds, then the call to definitelyShouldBeCalledAfterTheFirst is guaranteed to be made even if "some code" fails.

```
void foo()
{
    theFirst();
    try
    {
        // some code
    }
    finally
    {
        definitelyShouldBeCalledAfterTheFirst();
    }
}
```